# Other user can write -join and then bot will trigger the commend

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm making bot in python and I don't know how to make that other user can write -join and then bot will trigger the commend. My code currently is in cogs so I'm using @commands.command instead @bot.command. Here is my code:

```py
class GamesCog(commands.Cog, name="Games"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.command()
    async def game(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Find a second person to play dice or play against the bot. (-join/-bot)")
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File('game.jpg'))

        def check(msg):
            return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel and msg.content.lower() in ["-join", "-bot"]
    
        msg = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(GamesCog(bot))
    print('File games.py is ready')
```

I know that in the `return msg.author` author shouldn't be there, I just don't know what to replace it with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually doing nothing with the message, you're waiting for it, and then nothing

```py
msg = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check)

if msg.content.lower() == "-join":
    # Do something

elif msg.content.lower() == "-bot":
    # Do something
```

```py
def check(msg):
    return msg.channel == ctx.channel and msg.content.lower() in ["-join", "-bot"]
```

Comment: I know he's not doing anything yet, but the problem is that only the person who writes .game will be able to write -join and the bot will process it and execute the command, and my point is that one person can type .game and the other person can join it by typing -join and then the bot will execute the commands.

Comment: Oh well, then simply don't put the part `msg.author == ctx.author`. Check the edit